# good way to change React JS state

Tags: reactjs, deep-copy

```
{
 "user":{
  "auth":true,
  "sub_sq":[
   "1":{
    "createdAt":"2021-08-28"
   }
  ]
 },
 "sub":{
  "name":"123"
  "sub_sq":[
   "1":{
    "createdAt":"2021-08-21"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Hello
When changing the state object like above

When applying changes to a user object

1. Do I need to change the entire object after deep copying?
2. Or do you only apply changes after deepcopy to the user object?

I like the two(2) method, so I'm applying the first (deepcopy only changed object)

but I'm not sure if that's the right way to do it, so I'm asking for advice.

Thank you

Comment: Think of using spread operator

Comment: when you want to change something in the nested object , you need to create a new copy of the parent object and the object which you want to change . For example if you want to change something inside the user object , you need to make the copy of the `entire state` and a new copy of the `user` object . Its not needed to create a copy of  `sub` here as nothing is changed in it .

Comment: The more you have nesting the more it becomes difficult to update state as you need to make copies of all the nested levels . You can make use of libraries like immer - https://immerjs.github.io/immer/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you should only copy the stuff you don't change in your new state value. For example:

```
const newState = {
  ...oldState,
  user: {
    ...oldState.user,
    auth: false,
  }
}
```

More generally, it's considered a better practice to split a deeply nested state object into multiple states. That allows you to be more specific in your state updates and later in your state listeners (i.e. `useEffect`). For example, you could split your original state value into two variables:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({
  "auth": true,
  "sub_sq": [
    "1": {
      "createdAt":"2021-08-28"
    }
  ]
});
const [sub, setSub] = useState({
  "name": "123"
  "sub_sq": [
    "1": {
      "createdAt":"2021-08-21"
    }
  ]
});
```

If you insist on using a composite state, it's better to use a reducer to update each state "part" in a more controlled fashion. From [React's `useReducer` documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer):

> useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one

Comment: I just answered thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this is a nagging problem with state management. Using the spread operator or the suggested [`immer` library](https://immerjs.github.io/immer) is a good option. I myself have created the [`@rimbu/deep` library](https://github.com/rimbu-org/rimbu/tree/main/packages/deep) for this. It has a method named `patch` that allows you to write things like:

```
import { patch } from '@rimbu/deep';

const person = {
  name: "Alice",
  age: 34,
  address: {
    street: "Random street",
    number: 45
  },
  friends: ["Bob", "Carol"]
};

const updatedPerson = patch(person)({
  age: v => v + 1,
  address: {
    street: "Other street"
  },
  friends: v => [...v, "Anne"]
})

// updatedPerson is now:
// {
//   name: "Alice",
//   age: 35,
//   address: {
//     street: "Other street",
//     number: 45
//   },
//   friends: ["Bob", "Carol", "Anne"]
// }
```

It's quite new and needs more documentation, but just wanted to share.

You can play around with this CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit rimbu-sandbox]